# Correct threshold for HoughCircles() circle detection opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to detect circles in an image with opencv in c++. I have tried various thresholds for the dp, parm1, and parm2 but I could not find the correct ones.

The radius of the circles is around 40 pixels.
I have added a link to sample images. Which values do I need to use in the HoughCircles() for correct results?

Link to sample [images](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlNEnGC079bRgbJZx4K48_euJzmlEg?e=hO31Yk).

Comment: I should maybe take a look at the documentation for this function (https://docs.opencv.org/master/dd/d1a/group__imgproc__feature.html#ga47849c3be0d0406ad3ca45db65a25d2d) which explains in detail how to chosse the function arguments.

Comment: Thanks, I have seen this, but it is for me not clear what parm1 parm2, and dp are doing. So I tried different values but it did not work for my sample images. Do you have a suggestion  which value I need to use so I can detect circles in all the sample images?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use following parameter values. These settings are able to detect the circles in your images.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::imread("75.bmp");
cv::Mat img_gray;
cv::cvtColor(img, img_gray, cv::COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
img_gray.convertTo(img_gray, CV_8UC1);
std::vector<cv::Vec3f> circles;
double minDist = 20;
double dp = 1;
double param1 = 200;
double param2 = 10;
int minRadius = 15;
int maxRadius = 25;
cv::HoughCircles(img_gray, circles, cv::HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp, minDist, param1, param2, minRadius, maxRadius);
if (circles.size() > 0) {
    for (size_t current_circle = 0; current_circle < circles.size(); ++current_circle) {
        cv::Point center(std::round(circles[current_circle][0]), std::round(circles[current_circle][1]));
        int radius = std::round(circles[current_circle][2]);
        cv::circle(img, center, radius, cv::Scalar(0, 255, 0), 1);
    }
}
```